# duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed -- still killing me

Tags: r

Have following import:

```
d5_17cou <- 
  read.table("[enter link description here][1]c_all_d5_imp.dat",
   header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="", dec=",", row.names=1, comment.char="",  strip.white=TRUE)
```

"row.names" are set to 1 in order to set the 1st column as row name.

I want to perform multiple correspondence analysis (MCA) using PCAmixdata.

I set required variables as factors, set various parameters:

```
d5_17cou <- within(d5_17cou, {
  a025r <- as.factor(a025r)
  a034r <- as.factor(a034r)
  a038r <- as.factor(a038r)
  a040r <- as.factor(a040r)
  a041r <- as.factor(a041r)
  a042r <- as.factor(a042r)
  c001r <- as.factor(c001r)
  c024r <- as.factor(c024r)
  c037r <- as.factor(c037r)
  charity <- as.factor(charity)
  clz.outgr4 <- as.factor(clz.outgr4)
  d019r <- as.factor(d019r)
  d023r <- as.factor(d023r)
  e014r <- as.factor(e014r)
  e018r <- as.factor(e018r)
  e035r <- as.factor(e035r)
  e114r <- as.factor(e114r)
  e143r <- as.factor(e143r)
  e146r <- as.factor(e146r)
  e190rr <- as.factor(e190rr)
  f022r <- as.factor(f022r)
  f028r <- as.factor(f028r)
  f051r <- as.factor(f051r)
  f064r <- as.factor(f064r)
  f066r <- as.factor(f066r)
  f121r <- as.factor(f121r)
  helpef <- as.factor(helpef)
  jpay <- as.factor(jpay)
  prices1 <- as.factor(prices1)
  psub.all <- as.factor(psub.all)
})
weight.row <- d5_17cou[,c(4)]
X.quali <- d5_17cou[,c(7:36)]
```

Then comes the MCA command line:

```
mca <- PCAmix(X.quanti=NULL,X.quali,ndim=5,weight.col=NULL,weight.row,graph=FALSE)
```

Followed by the error message:
**duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed**.

Which is strange, given that the code used to work a couple of years ago on the exact same data. Not this time.

**Have browsed most of the archive here for "duplicate row.names" error, tried a lot of the solutions there, and would still get the same error.** This is to say that a "try looking up this or that thread" kind of advice probably will not help -- what I need is more specific.

Even more bizarre, after adding the

```
row.names=1
```

subcommand to read.table this afternoon, it worked OK -- but not in the evening when I returned to the task, using the exact same script.

Data in question attached.

[Data file [Google Drive]](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NwcvwwaPLWaSmKOuQiVrWAK4iKn9f10S)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use row names. There's nothing in R that actually requires them, and they don't translate well to other environments (databases, other languages, etc)

Comment: No effect, still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by the fact that the row names are numbers, e.g., `199990901000,` which are larger than the greatest integer value `.Machine$integer.max` which is `2147483647`. While row names of a data.frame are of type character it might cause a problem in later processing steps, perhaps.

Therefore, I suggest to treat the first column as a regular data column and not as row.names.

The code below worked for me to read the file and to coerce many columns to factor:

```
library(data.table)
url <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", 
               "1NwcvwwaPLWaSmKOuQiVrWAK4iKn9f10S")
d5_17cou  <- fread(url, dec = ",", colClasses = list(character = 1L))
cols <- names(d5_17cou)[8:37]
d5_17cou[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = cols]
str(d5_17cou)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    22431 obs. of  39 variables:
>  $ S007      : chr  "199905600001" "199905600002" "199905600003" "199905600004" ...
>  $ S003A     : int  56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 ...
>  $ cou.year  : int  561999 561999 561999 561999 561999 561999 561999 561999 561999 561999 ...
>  $ year      : int  1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 ...
>  $ s017ay    : num  0.692 1.051 1.051 0.752 0.752 ...
>  $ uitem     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>  $ item      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>  $ a025r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
>  $ a034r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...
>  $ a038r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
>  $ a040r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ a041r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ a042r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ c001r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ c024r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
>  $ c037r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
>  $ charity   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
>  $ clz.outgr4: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
>  $ d019r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
>  $ d023r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
>  $ e014r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
>  $ e018r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
>  $ e035r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
>  $ e114r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ e143r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
>  $ e146r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
>  $ e190rr    : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
>  $ f022r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ f028r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
>  $ f051r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
>  $ f064r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
>  $ f066r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
>  $ f121r     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
>  $ helpef    : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
>  $ jpay      : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ prices1   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ psub.all  : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
>  $ oriend    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ dupl      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

Note that the first column `S007` is explicitely read in as character column (otherwise `fread()` uses `int64`) and is part of the dataset, now. Consequently, the numbering of all subsequent columns is changed.

BTW, `fread()` is *much* faster than `read.table()`.

Comment: Have used your code to read the file and set the variables.
However, still get the the same error message ("duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"):
    library(PCAmixdata, pos=4)
    weight.row <- d5_17cou[,c(5)]
    X.quali <- d5_17cou[,c(8:37)]
    mca <- PCAmix(X.quanti=NULL,X.quali,ndim=5,weight.col=NULL,weight.row,graph=FALSE)

Comment: The error occurs with the "PCAmix" command.
Two more things:
1/ The error occurs also in the absence of ANY row numbers or row number-like columns (i.e., even with a file containing columns 8 to 37 (a025r to psub.all) only.
2/ As mentioned earlier, the command run (no "duplicate 'row.names' error) a couple of days ago on a partial file (first 200 rows), but not since.
To recap: the row.name error is related to the PCAmix command, not to read.table of fread generally.

Comment: Update: Have reinstalled earlier versions of R (3.1.1) and the package (PCAmixdata 2.1) and now the command runs OK, no "duplicate 'row.names'" or, indeed, any "error" whatsoever.
Obviously, when the old code fails to work under the new version and no one seems to have a clue how to resolve the issue, the fault lies with the software, not with the user.